# JSON invalid character '}' looking for beginning of object key string

Tags: json, parse-platform, syntax-error

I am attempting to import a `.json` file to `parse.com`, and I have encountered many errors while doing so. I solved them sequentially, but after I click `finish import`, I get the error

```
invalid character '}' looking for beginning of object key string
```

My `JSON` script is, as far as I know, perfectly fine. But I only started using `JSON` two hours ago, so I'm sure there's something wrong with it.

```
{
  "results": [{
    "nameChunk1": [{
      "name1": "Sean",
      "name2": "Noah",
    }]
    "nameChunk2": [{
      "name1": "Joseph",
      "name2": "Sam",
    }]
  }]
}
```

So, where is the mysterious invalid `}`? I fear there are many... Keep in mind I am using `JSON` for importing data into `parse.com`

Comment: quite often bug-messages are not for the line they're complaining about, for for something missing (or extra) on a line previous. My best guess here is that you can't put a comma on the end of a dictionary/hash. Likewise, you're missing one between the two array elements.

Comment: Validate if your JSON is valid at http://jsonlint.com/

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Correct your JSON syntax:

```
{
  "results": [{
     "nameChunk1": [{
        "name1": "Sean",
        "name2": "Noah" 
     }],
     "nameChunk2": [{
       "name1": "Joseph",
       "name2": "Sam"
     }]
  }]
}
```

Observe that I have added `,` after each array.. and removed `,` after `name2` key.

Always use validators such as https://jsonlint.com to validate your JSON.

Comment: Thanks! I tried removing `,` after the `name2` value but it did not help. I see I need the comma after the arrays. It works now. Will accept when the 10 minute waiting period times out

Comment: If you have any other `key`:`value` pair after `name2`..then you definitely need the comma, otherwise it does not.

Answer (score 8):

Use any JSON validator like https://jsonlint.com to validate your JSON.

Correct JSON is:

```
{
  "results": [{
     "nameChunk1": [{
        "name1": "Sean",
        "name2": "Noah" 
     }],
     "nameChunk2": [{
       "name1": "Joseph",
       "name2": "Sam"
     }]
  }]
}
```

Answer (score 4):

There are two issues with the JSON:

1. There should be no ',' after last element of an object
2. There should be a comma to separate two elements

Below is the valid JSON:

```
{
  "results": [{
    "nameChunk1": [{
      "name1": "Sean",
      "name2": "Noah"
    }],
    "nameChunk2": [{
      "name1": "Joseph",
      "name2": "Sam"
    }]
  }]
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to remove the comma's after `name2` and then insert a comma between `nameChunk1` and `nameChunk2`.  Valid JSON below:

```
{
  "results": [{
    "nameChunk1": [{
      "name1": "Sean",
      "name2": "Noah"
    }],
    "nameChunk2": [{
      "name1": "Joseph",
      "name2": "Sam"
    }]
  }]
}
```