# How does mongoimport interpret JSON?

Tags: json, mongodb, npm

I've got a decently sized json file that I need to import into mongo to use as test data. However, when I attempt to use mongoimport, I receive the response

> Failed: error processing document #1: invalid character '}' looking for beginning of object key string

Here is a slice of the JSON I'm attempting to import. Note that removing the empty line did not fix the issue for me, and that suggestions found here [JSON invalid character '}' looking for beginning of object key string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29690789/json-invalid-character-looking-for-beginning-of-object-key-string) like running the JSON through a linter haven't fixed my issue. It is recognized as valid JSON, yet doesn't work with mongoimport.

```
[{
    "prompt_id": "id1",
    "prompt_text": "What is the best advice you’ve ever received? What were you doing at the time?"

},
{
    "prompt_id": "id2",
    "prompt_text": "Write from a ladybug’s point of view. What does a typical day look like for you?"

}]
```

Here is the terminal command I'm using

```
mongoimport --db testdb --collection prompts --file "fullfilepath\prompts.json"
```

My question is "How does mongoimport look at a JSON?" I'm guessing there is a wrapping piece it wants (called an object key string), but I'm unsure what that should look like.

Comment: What version of `mongoimport` are you using? It looks like your source JSON is an array, in which case you should be adding [`--jsonArray`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongoimport/#cmdoption-jsonarray) to correctly interpret the JSON. Note that the array approach is limited to imports of 16MB or smaller so may not be suitable for your "decently sized file".

Comment: The file is within the 16 MB boundary as it is just text, so that shouldn't be an issue. 

However, adding the `--jsonArray` to the command returned the exact same error as listed in the OP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer by using `mongoexport` on a collection that I had in the db, then iterating a single object in  my JSON until it `mongoimport`'d correctly. After that, it was just a few simple replace operations, resulting in my entire JSON importing correctly.

So, in response to my original question, **you need an object id (`_id` in the example below) for the `mongoimport` command to work.**

Here's what the JSON looked like when it was accepted:

```
{
    "_id":{
        "$oid": "69d4023e2cd5ac10f8b92d40"
    },
    "prompt_id": "promptid1",
    "prompt_text": "What is the best advice you’ve ever received? What were you doing at the time?"
}
{
    "_id":{
        "$oid": "69d4023e2cd5ac10f8b92d41"
    },
    "prompt_id": "promptid2",
    "prompt_text": "Write from a ladybug’s point of view. What does a typical day look like for you?""
}
```

Please also note that I used the same command, without requiring the `--jsonArray` flag.

```
mongoimport --db testdb --collection prompts --file "fullfilepath\prompts.json"
```